# Adding Custom Attribute In Audited Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audit, audit-logging, acts-as-audited

I want to add custom attributes in the Audit Log like `first_name, last_name` using audited gem. Any idea how I can update the values of my custom attributes ?

```
#<AuditLog id: 1, 
    auditable_id: 2, 
    auditable_type: "User", 
    associated_id: nil, 
    associated_type: nil, 
    user_id: 2, 
    company_id: nil, 
    user_type: "User", 
    username: nil, 
    first_name: nil, last_name: nil, action: "update", 
    audited_changes: {"first_name"=>["Name1", "Name2"]}, version: 8, 
    comment: nil, 
    remote_address: "::1", request_uuid: "ed24f0d3-7ca7-42b1-b1a4-202222b38f7c", created_at: "2022-01-28 17:59:08">
enter code here
```

My user model contains these two attributes

```
t.column :first_name, :string
t.column :last_name, :string
```

Answer (score 0):

It should just work.  The audit record doesn't store discrete fields, it stores a YAML or jsonb representation of all changed fields.  If you've added first_name to your users table, the audit record will automatically note any changes to that attribute.

Comment: I have updated the question